# Item Loaders not working properly in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to study Item Loaders in scrapy, this code below is not working properly: it gives me just the "start_url" value and not the "SUBJECT" and "CREATOR2" value (they don't appear at all, there is not just an empty slot). I can't figure out why it does that.

I need to use Item Loaders especially for the "CREATOR2" value, which is sometimes on an xpath and sometimes on another.

```
import scrapy
from bibtime.items import BibtimeItem, BibtimeLoader
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import Identity
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class bibtimeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "bibtime"
allowed_domains = ['www.example.com']
start_urls = [
www.example.com
]

def parse(self, response):
    l = BibtimeLoader(item=BibtimeItem(), response=response)
    start_url = response.request.url
    l.add_xpath('CREATOR2', '//font[@size="+1"]/center//preceding-sibling::text()[normalize-space()]')
    l.add_xpath('CREATOR2', '//link[@rel="schema.DC"]//meta[@name="DC.creator"]//@content[normalize-space()]')
    l.add_value('start_url', start_url)
    l.add_xpath('SUBJECT', '//link[@rel="schema.DC"]//meta[@name="DC.subject"][1]//@content[normalize-space()]')

    return l.load_item()
```

They are all named in the items file and the xpath work fine on a tester.

EDIT: As request, here's the item definition:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import Identity


class BibtimeItem(Item):
    CREATOR2 = Field()
    SUBJECT = Field()
    start_url = Field()
    pass

class BibtimeLoader(ItemLoader):
    #default_input_processor = Identity()
    default_output_processor = Identity()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the `|` (or) inside an XPath instead. Also, use the lower-cased field name:

```
l.add_xpath('creator2', '//font[@size="+1"]/center//preceding-sibling::text()[normalize-space()] | //link[@rel="schema.DC"]//meta[@name="DC.creator"]//@content[normalize-space()]')
```

Also, if you would check the XPath expressions in the Scrapy Shell, you would find out that they actually match nothing:

```
$ scrapy shell http://www.aib.it/aib/sezioni/emr/bibtime/num-i-1/bucchion.htm
>>> response.xpath('//font[@size="+1"]/center//preceding-sibling::text()[normalize-space()]')
[]
>>> response.xpath('//link[@rel="schema.DC"]//meta[@name="DC.creator"]//@content[normalize-space()]')
[]
```

I suspect this is happening because of the way `Scrapy` and `lxml` parses this particular non-well-formed HTML. You need to tweak your expressions, e.g.:

```
>>> response.xpath('//center/text()').extract_first()
u'Cinzia Bucchioni'
```

Comment: @LaraM. are you sure the XPath expressions are correct? Also, post the item and the item loader definition. Thanks.

Comment: Added the item and loader definition. Yes, I'm pretty sure, here's a page of example: view-source:http://www.aib.it/aib/sezioni/emr/bibtime/num-i-1/bucchion.htm

Comment: @LaraM. updated the answer with some more information, please check. Thanks.

Comment: It works! Thank you. Now I only have to correct the other xpath thanks :)